# Unable to login after switching to "multi-user" target in Yocto Linux

Tags: systemd, linux-kernel, selinux, yocto-project

I have a device running yocto(warrior) and `selinux` is enabled by default. I am unable to login to device if I switch to `multi-user` target. If I change selinux in `permissive` mode, I am able to login but I get `Unable to get valid context for root`.

In elaborative way,

- Once device is up in graphical mode I run `systemctl isolate multi-user` which takes me in console and for login id and password
- After giving correct credentials also I am unable to login
- Change selinux to permissive mode by `setenforce 0` and I am able to login but it gives me `Unable to get valid context for root`

I do not see any rules violation while running these commands:

- audit2allow -a
- audit2allow -d
- cat /var/log/messages | audit2allow -d

Please note that I am not creating any user. so the only user is `root`.

**Edit 01** :
`journalctl -f` shows an error `Failed to start User Runtime Directory /run/user/0` at the time of entering login details:

```
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 0.
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 systemd[1]: Starting User Runtime Directory /run/user/0...
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 systemd-logind[532]: New session c8 of user root.
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 systemd-user-runtime-dir[1053]: Failed to acquire runtime directory size: Access denied
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 systemd[1]: Failed to start User Runtime Directory /run/user/0.
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for User Manager for UID 0.
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=user-runtime-dir@0 comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 systemd[1]: user@0.service: Job user@0.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 systemd[1]: Started Session c8 of user root.
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 systemd[1]: getty@tty1.service: Succeeded.
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=getty@tty1 comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 systemd[1]: session-c8.scope: Succeeded.
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 systemd[1]: getty@tty1.service: Service has no hold-off time (RestartSec=0), scheduling restart.
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 systemd[1]: getty@tty1.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 12.
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 systemd-logind[532]: Session c8 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 systemd[1]: Stopped Getty on tty1.
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=getty@tty1 comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=getty@tty1 comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=getty@tty1 comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 0.
Oct 22 19:59:08 panther2 systemd-logind[532]: Removed session c8.
```